# JAVA jar file to exe error

Tags: java

When I try to make my jar file into an exe file, when I run it I get an error.  My java file while running in Eclipse works great.

Error occurred when starting the application:

I have used both exe4j and Launch4j.

exe4j gives this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at EasyExpress.<init>(EasyExpress.java:61)
at EasyExpress.main(EasyExpress.java:162)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where are you resources located?  Are the included within the Jar?

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause is most likely that you have used `Class.getResource` (or similar) to get the image from your application resource collection.  When that fails, it returns a `null`.  You have then passed that `null` to `ImageIO.read`.  Hence, the exception you are seeing.

The problem is likely to be one of the following:

- The resource is not in or available to the (ultimate) executable.
- The resource is there, but your application is using the wrong path.

Here's what I'd do.

1. Generate an executable JAR for the application using Eclipse.
2. Run that JAR ... outside of Eclipse (!) ... to see if you get the same problem.
3. If yes, then solve the problem in the context of the executable JAR.  It will be easier, and is highly likely that you will fix the problem for the generated `exe` file as well.
4. If no, then investigate how the `exe4j` tool handles resources and resource loading. (My brief read of the [exe4j documentation](https://resources.ej-technologies.com/exe4j/help/doc/help.pdf) did not highlight any obvious gotchas ...)

Comment: Ok, resource appears to not be there in the jar file. I changed the project a bit to have a bin folder etc. Where do I go about putting the image files so they get included in the jar?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to run it outside eclipse then you could make a JAR file. In eclipse click File > Export JAR > Select Java JAR File > select project > select destination to save to. Done